# Sefer Tehillim and Megillas Esther

Tags: tanach, tehilim-psalms, megillat-esther, bava-batra

Chazal give the following list of names for books of Tanach (Bava Basra 14b):

> סידרן של כתובים רות **וספר** תהלים ואיוב ומשלי קהלת שיר השירים וקינות דניאל **ומגילת** אסתר עזרא ודברי הימים
>
> The order of the Writings is Rus, **Book** of Tehillim, Iyov, Mishlei, Koheles, Shir HaShirim, Kinnos, Daniel, **Megillas** Esther, Ezra, Divrei HaYamim.

I've bolded two titles of books - *Sefer* Tehillim and *Megillas* Esther. All of them are Sefarim, and five ([four](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38742/9682)?) of them are Megillos, so why are these singled out?

Comment: It's probably just whatever names were common for them. No way to ever know why those were the popular terms. Note Massekhet Megillah about Ester. Clearly the term megillah was strongly associated with Ester in particular.

Comment: Consider checking manuscripts of the page such small details in wording frequently vary among manuscripts. If they all have it like this, it would strengthen the question.

Comment: @mevaqesh I don't have access to an Oz V'hadar and its Haghos v'Tziyunim, so if someone else does, feel free to mention if something shows up in there. Often they quote such variations there.

Comment: @mevaqesh Note also Megillas Taanis. I'd expect Megillas Kinnos to match.

Comment: I wonder if it originally said ספרי תהלים

Comment: How do you know five of them are Megillot? What does it mean to be a Megillah? I don't know what makes something a megillah frankly that I could define which books are or aren't megillos. though you may enjoy https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38742/759 imo it's likely length that's most operative (like megillat sotah), not unlike trei asar being put together as one unit, and indeed in some old manuscripts there are references to megillat chavakkuk or megillat chaggai etc. or even megillat k'ayal taarog (the second book of tehillim).

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks for the source - everyone throws around "chamesh megillos" and I'd never known where it actually comes from. It's noteworthy that of the four in Sofrim, Esther is the longest. Koheles is longer, but according to that discussion, its title seems to have come later.

Comment: @mevaqesh Already in the Mishnah Rosh Hashana 3:7 megillah just means esther.

Comment: I think you should just ask about tehillim. As noted above Esther is basically the only book called Megillah in Talmudic times and prior and it's often called that exclusively, so it's not at all weird that it's called that here.

Comment: @DoubleAA But there's the Braisa in Sofrim at least in the linked question that names four of them megillos. Why does this Braisa argue?

Comment: It's not arguing. It's reflecting a later language convention. There's no argument since no side is right or wrong. As I pointed out above lots of things have been called "megillot" at various times. In the Talmud and Mishna though it's basically just Esther and the quotes in this question are entirely consistent with that. If anything the only question is what's the deal with Soferim making up new Megillos?